# How do you load/store assets?

Tags: c++, sdl, spritesheet, asset-management

I'm new to C++ and SDL2 and for the past few days I've been trying to figure out what to do with/how to handle assets for my game. I'm using an asset pack that includes 4 characters and each character has 6 spritesheets and my goal is to be able to make an entity that I can give a set of sprites to use.

I've managed to achieve this:

```
this->factory.createPlayer(100.0f, 100.0f, characterSpriteSets["MaskDude"]);
this->factory.createPlayer(300.0f, 100.0f, characterSpriteSets["NinjaFrog"]);
this->factory.createPlayer(500.0f, 100.0f, characterSpriteSets["PinkMan"]);
this->factory.createPlayer(700.0f, 100.0f, characterSpriteSets["VirtualGuy"]);

Entity& createPlayer(float x, float y, const SpriteSet& spriteSet) {
    auto& entity = manager.addEntity();

    auto& position = entity.addComponent<Position>(x, y);
    auto& render = entity.addComponent<Render>(graphics);

    render.addSpritesFromSet(spriteSet);
    render.changeState("idle");

    return entity;
}
```

The problem though is I don't think the way I store(?) the sprites is ideal, so I'm curious what I could do to improve this.

```
struct AnimationData {
    std::string path;
    int frameCount;
};

using SpriteSet = std::map<std::string, AnimationData>;

std::map<std::string, SpriteSet> characterSpriteSets = {
    {
        "VirtualGuy",
        {
            {"idle", {"source/resources/animations/player/Virtual Guy/Idle (32x32).png", 11}},
            {"run", {"source/resources/animations/player/Virtual Guy/Run (32x32).png", 12}},
            {"jump", {"source/resources/animations/player/Virtual Guy/Jump (32x32).png", 1}},
            {"fall", {"source/resources/animations/player/Virtual Guy/Fall (32x32).png", 1}},
            {"doublejump", {"source/resources/animations/player/Virtual Guy/Double Jump (32x32).png", 6}},
            {"walljump", {"source/resources/animations/player/Virtual Guy/Wall Jump (32x32).png", 5}},
            {"hit", {"source/resources/animations/player/Virtual Guy/Hit (32x32).png", 7}},
        }
    },
    // Repeat for every object
};
```

Comment: Can you describe what it is about this approach that seems non-ideal to you? What would your ideal version accomplish that this does not, or in what specific ways should answers focus on making this "better"?

Comment: I think it might also be useful to mention if you are looking something that's more maintainable or better for performance. If you are not having any issues with the current approach, your time is better used working on new features.

Comment: @DMGregory I feel like adding onto a map like this will eventually become inefficient so I've been trying to see what other ways I could go about this

Comment: What type of inefficiency are you worried about? CPU time/latency? Memory use? Development velocity? Code complexity? Something else? There are a lot of different considerations we might prioritize in game development, and often they can lead to divergent solutions depending on our focus, so to give you the best help we can, we need a very clear idea of what your specific goals are for this code.